# Quiz app- pls given logic for quiz app in next button, prev button and skip button

Tags: android

"Below code working but when I select Q1-answer and clicked next button in gone to Q2 but when i clicked on previous button to going Q1 but repeat I click next button is show toast massage pls select the answer but already given Q1 answer pls help
"android code"

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"talent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.previous_button:
                if (que_position > 0) {
                    que_position--;
                 //setSelectedOption();
                    setPreviousQuestion();
                    IsSelectedAnswer=true;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.next_button:
                //sendAnswers();
                //setSelectedOption();
                if (IsSelectedAnswer) {
                    setSelectedOption();
                    sendAnswers();
                    que_position++;
                    //setAnswers(que_position - 1);
                    setQuestion();
                 /*if (isFinishTest) {
                        setAnswers(que_position - 1);
                        setSkipQuestion();
                    } else {
                        que_position++;
                        setAnswers(que_position - 1);
                        setQuestion();
                       //Toast.makeText(parent, "mistak", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }*/
                 } else {
                    Toast.makeText(parent, "Please Select Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //IsSelectedAnswer=false;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

"answer selection code"

```
private void setSelectedOption() {
        try {
            if(jsonArray.length()>0){
                boolean isAdded=false;
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    int questionposition=jsonObject.getInt("questionposition");
                    if(questionposition==que_position){
                            isAdded=true;
                        IsSelectedAnswer=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(isAdded){
                    //jsonArray.remove(que_position);
                }
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("questionposition",que_position);
                jsonObject.put("selectedoption",selectedOption);
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
            }else {
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("questionposition",que_position);
                jsonObject.put("selectedoption",selectedOption);
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

"seleted answer send to server"

```
public void sendAnswers() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
        String result = gson.toJson(results);
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        try {
            params.put("PaperId", PrefHelper.getString(PrefHelper.KEY_PAPER_ID, ""));
            params.put("QuestionId", QuestionId);
            params.put("Answer", Answer);
            params.put("StudentId", LoginHelper.getInstance().getStudent_Id());
            params.put("IsSkipped", IsSkipped);
            params.put("IsCorrect", IsCorrectAnswer);
            RestClient.getInstance().postRequest(parent, Request.Method.POST, ApiList.APIs.submitStudentAnswer.getUrl(), params, this, RequestCode.submitStudentAnswer, true, false, "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

"next question display"

```
public void setQuestion() {
        if (quizzes.size() != que_position) {
            setQuestionLayout();
            ExamQuestion quiz = quizzes.get(que_position);
            //QuizQuestionModel quiz = quizlist.get(que_position);
            setQue(quiz, que_position);
            Toast.makeText(parent, "yha pe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //   que_position++;
        } else {
            if (results.size() > 0) {
                FragmentNavigationInfo fragmentNavigationInfo = new FragmentNavigationInfo(ExamFinishFragment.newInstance(subjectName,topicName,String.valueOf(total_marks), String.valueOf(total_right_ans), String.valueOf(total_rightCount), String.valueOf(quizzes.size()), String.valueOf(total_skipped), String.valueOf(total_attempt), rightAnswers));
                parent.addFragment(fragmentNavigationInfo);
                //Toast.makeText(parent, "mistake", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // sendAnswers();
            }
        }
    }
```

"previ. question"

```
public void setPreviousQuestion() {
        if (quizzes.size() != que_position) {
            setQuestionLayout();
            ExamQuestion quiz = quizzes.get(que_position);
            //QuizQuestionModel quiz = quizlist.get(que_position);
            setQue(quiz, que_position);
            //  que_position++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do it like mentiond below, ask if need any help..
During the lifetime of the questions Activity, maintain either an array or shared preferences for each question index if it is answered or not. while setting a next or previous question check-in prefs if there is a reference against it check its value if it's true  and get the last checked

Comment: sir,thank you for given rpl.Pl's given example.

Comment: Follow edmt dev yt quiz app